# Post data using array in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to get data from example.com and post it to example.org.

casperjs code:

```
var data = [];
casper.start('http://example.com', function() {
    this.echo('opened');
});
casper.then(function() {
    data.push( this.getHTML('div#a') ); // first text
    data.push( this.getHTML('div#b') ); // second text
    // ...
});
casper.thenOpen('http://example.org/', {
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        'data_one': data[0],
        'data_two': data[1],
        // ...
    }
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo( data );
});
```

console result:

```
first text,second text,...
```

I am expecting to receive some data at example.org but everything I added ('data_one', 'data_two', ...) is undefined.

How can I post the data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you access `data[0]` and `data[1]`, before they are available.

CasperJS' execution is asynchonous. All `then*` and `wait*` functions are asynchronous step functions. Calling them only adds a step to the queue and only when `casper.run()` is called, the queue will be executed.

This means that by calling `casper.thenOpen()`, you directly access `data`, but the previous step wasn't yet executed, so it isn't yet populated.

For example, you can split `casper.thenOpen()` into `casper.then()` and `casper.open()`:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.open('http://example.org/', {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'data_one': data[0],
            'data_two': data[1],
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you can also nest steps. They are queued to be executed at the end of the current step:

```
casper.then(function() {
    data.push( this.getHTML('div#a') ); // first text
    data.push( this.getHTML('div#b') ); // second text

    ...

    this.thenOpen('http://example.org/', {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'data_one': data[0],
            'data_two': data[1],
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```